# Azure WebJobs PingException, .exe runs fine as a console application

Tags: c#, azure

I am attempting to build an Azure WebJob to check the status of a website every 5 minutes.  I built the job as a console application that works just fine.  When it is run, it will query a MySQL database for a list of websites, submit an HTTP request to the website and then log the status of that request in the MySQL database.  Like I said, from the console, this is working just fine.  When I zip it and add it as a web job, the part of my program that runs a Ping to get a response time is failing.  My code that runs the ping is:

```
    public ArrayList GetStatusList(ArrayList sites)
    {
        foreach (Website ws in sites)
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(ws.WebsiteUrl);
            webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) webRequest.GetResponse();
            ws.HttpStatus = response.StatusCode.ToString();
            Uri uri = new Uri(ws.WebsiteUrl);
            Ping pingClass = new Ping();
            PingReply pingReply = pingClass.Send(uri.Host);
            ws.ResponseTime = pingReply.RoundtripTime;
            ws.WebsiteCheckedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        }
```

The following it the error log from the Azure WebJob:

```
[02/01/2016 19:33:37 > c91ef2: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopped
[02/01/2016 19:33:57 > c91ef2: SYS INFO] Detected WebJob file/s were updated, refreshing WebJob
[02/01/2016 19:33:57 > c91ef2: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
[02/01/2016 19:33:57 > c91ef2: SYS WARN] 'Always On' doesn't appear to be enabled for this Web App. To ensure your continuous job doesn't stop running when the SCM host is idle for too long, consider enabling 'Always On' in the configuration settings for your Web App. Note: 'Always On' is available only in Basic, Standard and Premium modes.
[02/01/2016 19:33:57 > c91ef2: SYS INFO] Run script 'IsItAlive.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[02/01/2016 19:33:57 > c91ef2: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[02/01/2016 19:33:58 > c91ef2: INFO] Connected to DB, MySQL version : 5.5.45-log
[02/01/2016 19:33:58 > c91ef2: ERR ] 
[02/01/2016 19:33:58 > c91ef2: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException: An exception occurred during a Ping request. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper
[02/01/2016 19:33:58 > c91ef2: ERR ]    at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.InternalSend(IPAddress address, Byte[] buffer, Int32 timeout, PingOptions options, Boolean async)
[02/01/2016 19:33:58 > c91ef2: ERR ]    at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send(IPAddress address, Int32 timeout, Byte[] buffer, PingOptions options)
[02/01/2016 19:33:58 > c91ef2: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[02/01/2016 19:33:58 > c91ef2: ERR ]    at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send(IPAddress address, Int32 timeout, Byte[] buffer, PingOptions options)
[02/01/2016 19:33:58 > c91ef2: ERR ]    at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send(String hostNameOrAddress, Int32 timeout, Byte[] buffer, PingOptions options)
[02/01/2016 19:33:58 > c91ef2: ERR ]    at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send(String hostNameOrAddress)
[02/01/2016 19:33:58 > c91ef2: ERR ]    at IsItAlive.BusinessLogic.GetStatusOfSites.GetStatusList(ArrayList sites)
[02/01/2016 19:33:58 > c91ef2: ERR ]    at IsItAlive.Program.Main(String[] args)
[02/01/2016 19:33:58 > c91ef2: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766
[02/01/2016 19:33:58 > c91ef2: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 60 seconds
[02/01/2016 19:33:58 > c91ef2: SYS INFO] Status changed to PendingRestart
```

I'm sure that the answer is right in front of me, but I'm just not experienced enough to understand the error log.  Can someone help me understand why my Ping is causing a Ping Exception when run as a WebJob and not as a console application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper
```

From the looks of this line, You application is accessing something that is present on your machine but is not available on a Azure Web App Worker or is a restricted call by the Sandbox running on the Worker.

You can check more about the [Sandbox that runs on the App Service Workers here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).

On the above linked page one of the restrictions that may be causing the error is,

> **Networking Restrictions/Considerations**
>
> There are manifold restrictions in terms of network access from an
>   Azure Web App. This section outlines limitations specific to Azure App
>   Service; apps are, in addition, still subject to Azure's own
>   networking restrictions.
>
> **Network endpoint listening**
>
> The only way an application can be accessed via the internet is
>   through the already-exposed HTTP ( 80 ) and HTTPS ( 443 ) TCP ports;
>   applications may not listen on other ports for packets arriving from
>   the internet.  However, applications may create a socket which can
>   listen for connections from within the sandbox. For example, two
>   processes within the same app may communicate with one another via TCP
>   sockets; connection attempts incoming from outside the sandbox, albeit
>   they be on the same machine, will fail. See the next topic for
>   additional detail.

Comment: Well that's a bummer, but does explain why a ping wouldn't work.  Thanks.

Comment: Also having similar issues. Everything works fine locally but fails on azure. All requests/response are sent using 80/443 ports. Weird.